# Как правильно передавать параметры в запрос PDO ООП?

Tags: php, ооп, pdo

Добрый день есть такой метод

```
// Get All Rows
public function getAll($query, $params=[]) {

    try {
      $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query); // Подгатавливаем запрос, указывая $table как переменную
      $stmt->execute($params); // Выполняем запрос
      return $stmt->fetchAll(); // Поулчаем результаты

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      throw new Exception($e->getMessage()); // Вывод ошибки если не удалось подключиться к базе данных
    }    
}

$db = new Database();

// $getTable = $db->getAll('SELECT * from ?', ['product']);  -- Выдает ошибку что неверный запрос в базе данных :(
$getTable = $db->getAll('SELECT * from product'); // Не получает задать что бы product был отправлен в качестве параметра :
```

Как задать что бы можно было передавать названия product как параметр, а не вшить его query запрос?

Comment: нельзя параметризовать названия таблиц и полей. Если необходимо подставлять имя таблицы в запрос, то просто проверяйте его по белому списку и вставляйте в запрос.